# Jupyterlab - Error when trying to install jupyter_scheduler

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have tried to install jupyter_scheduler by using
**pip install jupyter_scheduler** but i keep getting the error message:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter_scheduler (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyter_scheduler

Can someone help me understand how i can fix this error message?
Kind Regards
Steve

i tried to download it via Notebook and command prompt and i am expecting for the Jupyter schedule to download.

Comment: What is the version of your `jupyterlab`? You can find it from the terminal via `jupyter --version` or via `!jupyter --version` within a notebook.